# How to test error handling with RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I try to test this code:

```
mail = Mail.new
mail.from = @from
mail.to = to
<...>
begin
  mail.deliver
rescue
  return false
else
  return true
end
```

for error handling with RSpec:

```
it 'should return true if success' do
  expect(mailer.send_confirmation_request(token)).to be true
end

it 'should return false if fails' do
  allow_any_instance_of(Mail).to receive(:deliver).and_raise('Mail error')
  expect(mailer.send_confirmation_request(token)).to be false
end
```

But it doesn't work: second test failed. Why does `allow_any_instance_of` (and `allow(Mail)`) not work in this way? How that can be tested? Should am I fix my code to be more testable? I can test it by stubbing Mail#new with rspec double, but it leads to stubbing all mail methods and not looks like a right way to do.

If it does matter, I use [mikel's mail gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail) and make tests according to his [recommendations](https://github.com/mikel/mail#using-mail-with-testing-or-specing-libraries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mail.new` doesn't return an instance of `Mail`, it returns an instance of `Mail::Message`, so you're calling `allow_any_instance_of` on the wrong class.

I assume the library does this to simplify the interface, but it is a little counterintuitive.

Comment: You are definitely right. [Here is](https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/master/lib/mail/mail.rb) it happens on the 50th string. Really unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

When you mock or stub a method using `expect_any_instance_ or`allow_any_instance_`, you're actually replacing the normal value of that method with what you return in the stub.

You can use `and_call_original` if you want to preserve the original implementation of the method call.

Relevant RSpec docs: 
https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-14/docs/message-expectations/calling-the-original-method